# Javascript search div with includes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a filter function with includes. What I have now already able to filter but the problem now is the background color won't disappear if there is not input in fields.

For example, after I did my first filter, the background color is already there, but second time, even the char doesn't match with the content, background color still remain there.

I've inserted snippet, you may try to insert any char to see the result, then clear field and click search again.

Would appreciate if anyone of you can help me. Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  if (input.value !== '') {
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      } else {
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<table align="center" width="20%">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 10px">
      <input type="text" id="Search" title="Type in a name">
      <button onclick="myFunction()">
        Click to search
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div class="target">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
<div class="target">
  This is another Div element.
</div>
<div class="target">
  Can you find me?
</div>
```

Comment: But, do you want to get the white bg back?

Comment: Instead of `return false` undo your changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
      var input = document.getElementById("Search");
      var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
      var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
      for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
        if (input.value !== '') {
          if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
            nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
          } else {
            nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
          }
        }
      }

    }
```